# Mary L Boas - 3.6.11

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, rotations

> The equations
>   $$
> \begin{cases} x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-z),\\
> y'=\frac{1}{2}(x+y\sqrt{2}+z),\\
> z'=\frac{1}{2}(x-y\sqrt{2}+z),\end{cases}\quad 
> \begin{cases} x''=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y'-z'),\\
> y''=-\frac{1}{2}(x'\sqrt{2}+y'+z'),\\
> z''=\frac{1}{2}(-x'\sqrt{2}+y'+z'),\end{cases}
> $$
>   represent rotations of axes in three dimensions. Find the matrix of the resultant rotation and describe geometrically the net result of the two rotations.

Lets say this is the matrix we need:
$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{\begin{pmatrix}
x'''\\y'''\\z'''
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}& \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{8}} & \frac{-2+\sqrt{2}}
{4}\\
\frac{-2+\sqrt{2}}{4}& \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1-2\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{8}}& \frac{2\sqrt{2}+1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}}
$$
$\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{How to interpret, lets say, the rotation of  $x$ axis?}}$

I basically forgot that matrix multiplication is not commutative. Correct matrix should be this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'''\\y'''\\z'''
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

A result - the $90 ^\circ$ rotation around $z$ axis.

Comment: It will be hard to answer that question, since that's **not** a rotation. It's not even close.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well this problem has very explicit answer the book. Actually similar problem in two dimensions is pretty easy to solve using a rotation matrix, but in 3d i can't really grasp how to apply it.

Comment: What does the title mean? Could you change it to something that gives a clue as to what the question is about?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Chapter 3 - Linear equations; vectors, matrices, and determinants. Section 6 - Matrix operations. Problem 11. The task is practically quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is *not* the right matrix. The right matrix is$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}4 & \frac{-2-\sqrt{2}}4 \\ \frac{-2-\sqrt{2}}4 & \frac14 &   \frac{1-2\sqrt2}4 \\ \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}4 & \frac{1+2\sqrt2}4 & \frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$Its only real eigenvalue is $1$, its complex non-real eigenvalues are $\pm i$, and its eigenvectors are the multiples of $\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2,-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$. Therefore, it represents a rotation of $\frac\pi2$ radians around the line passing through the origin and $\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2,-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$. This can be checked as follows: if$$e_1=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right),\ e_2=\left(0,-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right),\text{ and }e_3=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right),$$then $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$, $A.e_1=e_1$, $A.e_2=e_3$, and $A.e_3=-e_2$.

Comment: I see, but how to approach it with {x'=x cosθ+ysinθ, y'=-x sinθ+y cosθ? I'm not yet familiar with eigenvalues.

Comment: I've added more details to my answer, but note that the notation used in your comment is not appropriate for rotations in space.

Comment: Such notation is given in the book. It might be obsolete, since edition is circa 1983.

Comment: I very much doubt that it is obsolete. It is just that when you write $x'=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta$ and $y'=-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$, you are clearly thinking about rotations in $\mathbb R^2$, not in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the books states that this method can be used for any number of variables, say x, y, z in three dimensions.